# JaveFX TriangleMesh Pyramid - it works, but why?

Tags: java, javafx

Making a 4-sided pyramid is explained 'lightly' in a few texts, as follows:

```
pyramid.getPoints().addAll(0,0,0); //0 = top
pyramid.getPoints().addAll(0, height, -hypotenuse/2); //1 = closest
pyramid.getPoints().addAll(-hypotenuse/2, height, 0); //2 = leftest
pyramid.getPoints().addAll(hypotenuse/2, height, 0); //3 = furthest
pyramid.getPoints().addAll(0, height, hypotenuse/2); //4 = rightest

pyramid.getTexCoords().addAll(0, 0);

pyramid.getFaces().addAll(0,0,2,0,1,0); //Left front side
pyramid.getFaces().addAll(0,0,1,0,3,0); //???
pyramid.getFaces().addAll(0,0,3,0,4,0); //Right back side
pyramid.getFaces().addAll(0,0,4,0,2,0); //???
pyramid.getFaces().addAll(4,0,1,0,2,0); //Bottom triangle at front???
pyramid.getFaces().addAll(4,0,3,0,1,0); //Bottom triangle right???
```

It works, but I don't understand it.

[image]

The 2nd face added has vertices 0, 1, 3, so (reference figure) ... it slices the pyramid in half. It is not an external face as far as I can tell.
Same with the 4th face, only now the slice is orthogonal to the 2nd face. And then the last 2 faces, which should be the triangles making up the square base of the pyramid. The first one goes from vertex 4 to vertex 1 to vertex 2, so ... that is the front triangle of the pyramid base (is what I think). So I expect vertices 2,3,4 to form the back triangle of the pyramid base, but in the last line of code we see vertices 4,3,1, which (according to my logic) make up the right triangle of the pyramid base, i.e. does not complement the front triangle of the pyramid base. Can someone please explain this on-the-face-of-it simple geometric puzzle? And is there a proper indepth resource out there I can study?

Much obliged - Michael

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm new to this. In which way is my question not Minimal, Complete, verifiable?

Comment: I can't copy and paste it to run it on my machine. That means it's not Complete.

Comment: Vertices 3 and 4 appear to be reversed in your image. (Just ignore the (identical) y-coordinates in vertices 1-4 and plot them in 2D.) If you transpose those two vertices, all the faces make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct numbering of the vertices is (apologies for the crudely-drawn image):

[image]

which you can see fairly clearly by plotting vertices 1-4 in the x-z plane:

```
1: (0, -h/2)
2: (-h/2, 0)
3: (h/2,  0)
4: (0,  h/2)
```

[image]

Thus the faces

```
(0,2,1)
(0,1,3)
(0,3,4)
(0,4,2)
(4,1,2)
(4,3,1)
```

describe exactly the triangles you want.

Comment: Many thanks! It is clearly wrong in the book I bought (JavaFX Introduction by Example), where the comments suggested the ordering as per my figure, but of course you are right I should have looked at the actual values passed in to mesh.getPoints.addAll(...). Apologies, and thanks again...

Comment: @M.Kemper If this answer solved your problem please accept it by clicking the checkmark icon to its left.

Comment: Happy to do so, if only I could find that checkmark icon... Can you/anybody explain where that is? - Michael